# change dropdown to a <div> and vice versa with jQuery on resize?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take a  and display it as a dropdown menu when the screen resizes to less than 700px. I can do this, but when the screen resizes once again to a greater size than 701, I need to make the  reappear as a normal , not a dropdown. Any idea on how I can make this happen?

Here is an example:
*resize the screen in this jfiddle to see the dropdown. I need to resize once again to just see the original*

jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rwj6oxc7/

HTML:

```
<div id="testing2" >
    <div  id="1" > 1 </div>
    <div  id="2" > 2 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).on("resize", function () {
    var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
    if ($theWindowSize <= 700) {
      var sel = $('<select id="tesing2"/>');
      $("#testing2 div").each(function () {
        sel.append(
          "<option value=" + this.id + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
        );
      });

      $("#testing2").replaceWith(sel);
    }
    else if ($theWindowSize >= 701) {
    //??? show <div id=testing2/> as a normal <div>  ???
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are replacing your `divs` with select-box so that element doesn't exist so you need to create them again.So, for that loop through options from select get `value` and `text` from option and append them inside div

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
    if ($theWindowSize <= 700) {
      var sel = $('<select id="tesing2"/>');
      $("#testing2 div").each(function() {
        sel.append(
          "<option value=" + this.id + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
        );
      });
      $("#testing2").replaceWith(sel);
    } else if ($theWindowSize >= 701) {

      var div = $('<div id="testing2"/>');
      //loop through each option
      $("#tesing2 option").each(function() {
      //append divs with value(id) and inner html
        div.append(
          "<div id=" + this.value + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</div>"
        );
      });
      //replace it with select
      $("#tesing2").replaceWith(div);

    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="testing2">
  <div id="1"> 1 </div>
  <div id="2"> 2 </div>
</div>
```

Or other way you don't need to create them just hide/show required elements depending on width of screen.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //create selcts
  var sel = $('<select id="tesing2"/>');
  $("#testing2 div").each(function() {
    sel.append(
      "<option value=" + this.id + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
    );
  });
  $(".main_div").append(sel); //append in main div
  $("#tesing2").hide() //hide it by default
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
    if ($theWindowSize <= 700) {
      $("#tesing2").show() //show or hide same
      $("#testing2").hide()
    } else if ($theWindowSize >= 701) {

      $("#tesing2").hide()
      $("#testing2").show()
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main_div">
  <div id="testing2">
    <div id="1"> 1 </div>
    <div id="2"> 2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create a **function** and call this on **ready + resize** method. 
I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

**[Check on Full Page]**

```js
var is_set = false; 
var div = $('<div id="testing2"/>');
var sel = $('<select id="testing2"/>');

function ListToDropdown(){  
  var $theWindowSize = $(window).width();
  if ($theWindowSize <= 700) {
    if (is_set == false){
      $("#testing2 div").each(function(v,h) {  
        sel.append(
          "<option value="+this.id +">" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
        );
      });
      //div set to empty
      div.html('');
      // replace it with div
      $("#testing2").replaceWith(sel);
    }
    is_set = true;
  }
  else if ($theWindowSize >= 701) { 
    if (is_set == true){
      $("#testing2 option").each(function() {
        div.append(
          "<div id="+this.value+">" + this.innerHTML + "</div>"
        );
      });
      //select set to empty
      sel.html('');
      //replace it with select
      $("#testing2").replaceWith(div);
    }
    is_set = false
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  ListToDropdown();
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
    ListToDropdown();  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="testing2">
  <div id="1">1</div>
  <div id="2">2</div>
  <div id="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To build off your code:

```
<div id="div" >
  <div  id="1" > 1 </div>
  <div  id="2" > 2 </div>
</div>
```

then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(window).on("resize", function () {
      var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
      if ($theWindowSize < 700) {
          var sel = $('<select id="select"/>');
          $("#div div").each(function () {
             sel.append(
               "<option value=" + this.id + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
             );
          });

         $("#div").replaceWith(sel);
      }else {
        var div = $('<div id="div"/>');
        $("#select option").each(function () {
           div.append(
           "<div id=" + this.value + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</div>"
           );
        });

       $("#select").replaceWith(div);
     }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes in HTML and jquery function.
Please try this, if you can not understand this then let me know I will explain to you.

HTML

```
<div class='responsive_div'>
  <div id="testing2" >
    <div  id="1" > 1 </div>
    <div  id="2" > 2 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    is_set = false
    $(window).on("resize", function () {
      var $theWindowSize = $(this).width();
      if ($theWindowSize <= 700) {
        if (is_set == false){
          options = ''
          $("#testing2 div").each(function () {
            console.log("hello", this.id)
            options += "<option value=" + this.id + ">" + this.innerHTML + "</option>"
          });
          $('.responsive_div').html('<select id="tesing2">'+ options +'</select>')
        }
        is_set = true
      } else if ($theWindowSize >= 701) {
        console.log("else part is excuted ");
        $('.responsive_div').html("<div id='testing2'><div id='1'> 1 </div><div id='2'> 2 </div></div>")
        is_set = false
      }
    });
  });
```